# Why is my component not rerendering after I change states?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, axios

I have a ul component and I want to rerender all of the children li when i complete an ajax request. After the ajax request completes I pass the response.data to the state. I can console.log the state and see that the data has changed, however the children never rerender.

```
export class Tiles extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            items: []
        };

         this.itemList = this.state.items.map((items)=>{
            return <ModalTest key={item.id} items={items}/>
        });
    }



    //This is the local fake data standing in for the real DB
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/tiles/')
            .then((res)=>{
                console.log(res.data);
                this.setState({items:res.data});
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul className="tiles-ul">
                {this.itemList}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `constructor` function run only once. It does not run after every `state` update. That means the code

```
    this.itemList = this.state.items.map((items)=>{
        return <ModalTest key={item.id} items={items}/>
    });
```

run only once when `state.items` is an empty array. So `this.itemList` will always be empty in your case.

To render the item list on every update you may consider creating the array in `render` method because `render` method runs on every `state` update.

```
renderItemList = () => {
    return this.state.items.map((items)=>{
       return <ModalTest key={item.id} items={items}/>
    });
}
render() {
    return (
       <ul className="tiles-ul">
          {this.renderItemList()}
       </ul>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your presentation code of tiles list in render or in the own method.

```
export class Tiles extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            items: []
        };

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/tiles/')
            .then((res)=>{
                console.log(res.data);
                this.setState({items:res.data});
            });
    }

    displayItemList() {
        return this.state.items.map((items)=>{
            return <ModalTest key={item.id} items={items}/>
        });
     }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul className="tiles-ul">
                {this.displayItemList() }
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
```